# which is faster method to traverse an array

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

Compare following two codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i<array_size; i++)
  cout << array[i] << endl;
```

OR

```
int* p_end = array+array_size;
for (int* p_array = array; p_array != p_end; p_array++)
  cout << *p_array << endl;
```

Which one is faster?

Another question is if we just want to traverse then which is faster: link list or array? Thankyou!

Comment: Those two loops have completely different terminating conditions.

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges. They aren't equivalent. The second one relies on a zero sentinel at the end of the array, which most arrays don't have.

Comment: say both have same terminating condition, i<array_size; then which will be faster, remember I'll have to take a counter i as well and increment it in the second case.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri No you won't. `int *p_end = array + array_size;` and the condition in your for-loop becomes `p_array != p_end`. With that the two loops are considerably similar.

Comment: If your question has changed, be sure it's reflected in the actual question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`array[i]` is **potentially** faster because the compiler knows you're not aliasing your pointer to someplace you really shouldn't.

Lists are much slower to traverse because of indirection imposed inbetween every node - this will ruin your caches and cause many a cache miss, which is probably the worst thing that can happen to a modern processor.

Comment: A list can be cached just the same way as an array (except that you may be wasting space if you don't use full cache lines). Problem is the execution dependency between the elements preventing you from running them in parallel on modern HW.

Comment: @Leeor Ehh, actually, how on Earth do you want to force the prefetching engine to actually prefetch nodes that are all over the RAM? And lists nodes do not have to be executionally dependent actually, in spite of their sequential nature, the data can be independent. I disagree with both of your points.

Comment: If it's caches, you don't need to prefetch. Only once the size is such that it spills out of the cache, sequentially traversing an array would indeed be much more prefetch friendly. As for the second point - we're talking about traversing - a list is sequential by nature, you can't have random access there unless you store pointers externally somehow. Actually I don't know what does the list have to do with what OP asked, your first line is fine (although array storage may also alias, but it's less likely to)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is likely to be faster on an array.

The second one terminates on finding a zero entry in the structure.  It really isn't the same thing.  But suppose you changed your code to read:

```
p_array = array;
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i, ++p_array)
    cout << *p_array << endl;
```

That loop would probably take the same amount of time as the first one with any modern compiler.  (In all actuality, the cost of `cout` would swamp everything anyway.)

The best approach for iterating through a container is really dictated by the container.  `vector<T>` allows O(1) random access via `operator[]`.  Also, its iterators offer O(1) `operator++`.  In contrast, a container like `list<T>` only lets you use `operator++`, and it's O(1).

And final thought:  You likely want to stick to pre-increment instead of post-increment in C++ when you can.

Comment: If the `list<T>` you refer to is `std::list`, it has no `operator[]`.

Comment: For some reason I thought it did.  I guess I was remembering a non-standard `list<>` I dealt with once.  My allergy to O(N) random access compelled me to avoid doing such a thing anyway.  In any case, accessing the Nth item of a `list<>` is O(N).

Comment: The thing is, traversing, at least to me, simply means "foreach" sort of concept -> go from the beginning to end in something that is considered a natural order if that makes any sense :).

Answer (score 0):

Note the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i<array_size; i++)
  cout << array[i] << endl;
```

Each loop you must - **compare i to array size, increment i, *add i to array***

```
int* p_end = array+array_size;
for (int* p_array = array; p_array != p_end; p_array++)
  cout << *p_array << endl;
```

Each loop you must - **compare p_array to p_end, increment p_array** *(there is no add here)*

So it would seem that the second loop - becuase it does not have to do an add should be faster

However - optimizers can do quite a lot so I would recommend compiling both and then comparing the asm for each loop

Also for your second question - Arrays are faster than linked lists to traverse because of the load time for each node and because they take more memory so fewer nodes can be cached